# Adding New rules to Sonarqube DB without restarting server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-4.0

How to add register new rule in sonarqube without restarting the server.
I have 50 rules in one quality profile and while analysing am using violation.xml which contains new rule which is not registered in sonar database so while analysis i need to check with sonar database and if rules not available and it need to add in sonar database and analysis should continue.
How can i do this adding rule without restarting server? pls help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. New rules are registered during server startup and there are no workarounds yet.
If it's a real critical need, you should discuss about this new feature on the mailing-list.